# How to set a nillable attribute for SOAP::Lite object in Perl?

Tags: perl, soap

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Exception: Error code: , messge: com.sun.istack.XMLStreamException2: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.3.1: Attribute 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance,nil' must not appear on element 'v1:get_list', because the {nillable} property of 'v1:get_list' is false. at ./soap.pl line 42.
```

This is my Perl code:

```
    my $client = SOAP::Lite
                ->on_fault( \&faultHandler )
                ->uri('http://api.domain.net/')
                ->proxy('https://api.domain.net/MyAPI');

        # Execute             
          $client->get_list();
```

How do I change/add the nillable attribute and how ?

Comment: Apparently Perl set nillable true if the function doesn't contain parameters get_list(). the schema on the server is the one that doesn't like it. it expect false not true. So the SOAP::Lite is not good here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How do I change/add the nillable attribute and how ?*

You use SOAP::Data to create argument for get_list, or for call

Switch to SOAP::Simple , it has better WSDL support `cpan BERLE/SOAP-Simple-0.00_03.tar.gz`